# I get "Error: class not found" when trying to use javap

Tags: java, javap

I'm trying to view the *bytecode* of my class but doesn't find the class even though the `.class` file is there. I can compile the `Main.java` file just fine from the CLI but when using `javap -c Main` it doesn't find the class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int Y = 0;
        int X = (Y + 4) * 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any other actions you've done? Just typing your commands from one console works fine for me.

Comment: No package? Classpath is correct?

Comment: @DaveNewton do you remember about default package? :)

Comment: @madhead Yes. I'm asking if there is in fact no package, and if the classpath is correct; obvious questions when there's a classpath issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've tested this code. It is good without the package. And javac/javap works too.

Comment: @madhead Which indicates a package or classpath problem on the part of the OP: look at the error message.

Comment: @DaveNewton Error message can indicate that OP runs javap from another dir. Or that OP has package in his code, but didn't posted it here. But for the **posted** code everything works great.

Comment: @madhead... Which would be a package or classpath problem, which is what I said. I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: So how would I fix the classpath and package issue?

Answer (score 8):

If the class is in the default package, and if you are in the directory where the Main.class file is, the use

```
javap -cp . -c Main
```

If your class is in the package com.foo.bar, then go th the directory where the Main.class file is (bar), then execute the following commands:

```
bar> cd ..
foo> cd ..
com> cd ..
> javap -cp . com.foo.bar.Main
```